# Need help adding a node in sorted LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to add a new Customer object (which should be node.data, not node) in sorted order by the customer object's name alphabetically. But it's not working. It's printing out the list in unsorted order (unchanged from original order).

```
public void  add(Customer newNode, int dummy){
   if (head == null){ // The first node
      head = tail = this;
      head.setData(newNode);
      size=1;
      return;

   }else{
       CustomerList last = null;
       for(CustomerList node = head; 
               node != null && node.getData().toString().compareTo(newNode.name) < 0; 
                    node = node.next){
          last = node; 

       }
       CustomerList newList = new CustomerList(newNode);
       newList.setNext(last.next);
       last.next = newList;
   }

} // add
```

Input of Customer objects from txt file. Should print out again but in alphabetical order (customer name).

```
10121,Airgo Fresh ods,OH,870023
10125,Bird Out fittered ,MI,870023
10134,Kit river ,IL,870023
10167,Mouin Gontaods,OR,870021
10178,Theiasu El senter,CA,870022
```

Code which reads data from txt file and creates objects and adds to list:

```
public void byCustomerName()
 {
 records = null;
 System.gc();
 CustomerList.setHead(null);
 records = new CustomerList();
 try
  {
  String line;
  StringTokenizer st;
  String id, name, state, salesrep;
  BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Customer.txt"));
  while ((line = infile.readLine()) != null)
      {
      st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
      id = st.nextToken(",");
      name = st.nextToken(",");
      state = st.nextToken(",");
      salesrep = st.nextToken(",");
      records.add(new Customer(id, name, state, salesrep), 99);
      }
  infile.close();
  } catch (IOException x) { System.err.println(x); } 
 } // byCustomerName
```

Comment: Did you try to debug?

Comment: Why don't you just sort it using Collections.sort() method? You may need to implement Comparable, to customize sorting.

Comment: @Sudhanshu, this is homework so I can't use Collections.sort(). I need to implement it myself.

Comment: can you post the input and it's expected output?

Comment: @Drakosha, I can't figure out the problem. I think there's something wrong with my logic. I was hoping someone might guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Or try to add `B, A` and will get some idea.

Comment: @An Alien - Please **spell out** the logic you're trying to implement.

Comment: what is the output you are getting?

Comment: @Azodious no change in output. Same as input.

Comment: beacause name is already in sorted order. :) shuffle the input and then check the output.

Comment: @Azodious, actually I made up those names and it's a coincidence that they were in alphabetical order. The input was given to me by my professor so I changed it around a bit.

Comment: so, did you get the problem now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually did this same exact assignment two semesters ago but decided to take the class again because I was unable to take the final. But since no programming for two semesters, I'm now extremely rusty. I'm just going to give up for now and use my old solution that I came up for the first time I took the class.

Solution:

```
public void add(Customer newNode, int dummy) {  
    CustomerList before = null;
    boolean inserted = false;
    if (head == null) {  //first node   
        head = tail = this;
        head.setData(newNode);
        return;
    } else {
        CustomerList curr = head;
        while(curr != null) {
            String currentName = curr.getData().getName();
            String newNodeName = newNode.name;
            if (currentName.compareToIgnoreCase(newNodeName) > 0) {

                CustomerList cList = new CustomerList(newNode);
                cList.setNext(curr);//curr is greater than clist, therefore cList's next element is curr
                if(before!=null)
                    before.setNext(cList);
                else {  //this tests the case when 
                    //the newNode goes at the BEGINNING of the list
                    head = cList;
                }
                curr = cList;
                inserted = true;
                return;
            }
            before = curr;
            curr = curr.next;               
        }
    }
    if(!inserted) {
        add(newNode);
    }

} // add
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your code has all sorts of problems in it. For one, I don't ever see you updating `head` or `tail` if you replace the first or last element. Also, there is no check for `last` potentially being `null`. It'll be hard to say more without knowing how some of your underlying `CustomerList` items work.

Answer (score 0):

As Sudhanshu already told you can use `Collections.sort(-)` method on your `List` object or as an alternate just use `TreeSet` in case if you want unique objects. Its better to utilize inbuilt methods of `java API` as these are less error prone and more reliable, at the same time you can reduce your code and time to mug up in it.